# Print all elements in a comma separated String

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I have a simple string that is generated dynamically as such:

String values = "one, two, three...last"

How to i print all items in string values?

Comment: [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You can try like below:-

```
for (x in "one, two, three...last".split(", ")) {
   println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` and `trim` like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input: String = "one, two, three, four, five, last"
    // split the String by comma and trim each result
    var result: List<String> = input.split(",").map { it.trim() }
    // you can print the items of the list in a differently separated String again
    println(result.joinToString(separator = ";") { it -> "\"${it}\"" })
}
```

the result is

```
"one";"two";"three";"four";"five";"last"
```